# How to properly configure YT gem? Yt::Errors::Forbidden

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, youtube-api

I am trying to use yt gem to access youtube API but I am having a problem.
I have added gem: `gem 'yt', '~> 0.28.0'`

Added configuration in application.rb

```
    Yt.configure do |config|
  config.client_id = '263440616399-n3ksvskq6oo843sgg0uddq14isvkon8m.apps.googleusercontent.com'
  config.client_secret = 't3lHoxu5YgwwD0pyYZXfUPMw'
  config.api_key = 'AIzaSyCvrisogh8SG-zKizLQxiCeUv403jOdov0'
end
```

I am trying this line on rails console:

```
account = Yt::Account.new access_token: 'ya29.GlsRBTrtujRlfReAsdIy6kNRE4ypzq2CTmGrz2vcvlrbNavef0qffPp0piara1X7aXcjZv2F79lBLO_D7DRoW0gnvqK0yTM8UOQC7pyaTyjoYaLBmTeUmIbm8xsOAgm'
```

It is returning Account Object:

```
#<Yt::Models::Account:0x000000046aabe0 @access_token="ya29.GlsRBTrtujRlfReAsdIvcy6kNRE4ypzq2CTmGrz2lrbNavef0qEyPp0piara1X7aXcjZv2F79lBLO_D7DRoW0gnvqK0yTM8UOQC7pyaTyjoYaLBmTeUmIbm8xsOAgm", @refresh_token=nil, @device_code=nil, @expires_at=nil, @authorization_code=nil, @redirect_uri=nil, @force=nil, @scopes=nil, @authentication=nil>
```

After that, I am trying to access account.email but getting an error:

```
Yt::Errors::Forbidden: {"request_curl":"curl -X GET -H \"content-length: 0\" -H \"user-agent: Yt::Request (gzip)\" -H \"authorization: Bearer ya29.GlsRBTrtujRlfReAsdIy6kNRE4ypzqvc2CTmGrz2lrbNavef0qEyPp0piara1X7aXcjZv2F79lBLO_D7DRoW0gnvqK0yTM8UOQC7pyaTyjoYaLBmTeUmIbm8xsOAgm\" -H \"host: www.googleapis.com\" \"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?key=AIzaSyCvriso2u8SG-zKizLQxiCeUv403jOdov0\"","response_body":{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"insufficientPermissions","message":"Insufficient Permission"}],"code":403,"message":"Insufficient Permission"}}}
```

Using Rails 4.2.8, Ruby 2.2.2

Any help, suggestions would be strongly and sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The insufficient permissions error is returned when you have not requested the scopes you need when you retrieved your access token. You need to request the following two scopes in order to get the information you need

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login

Using the yt gem you can make the request to the URL generated below from your web application:

```
account = Yt::Account.new(scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"], redirect_uri: 'YOUR REDIRECT URL').authentication_url
```

Use the code parameter received along the request to the redirect URL to authenticate and initialize the account:

```
account = Yt::Account.new authorization_code: 'code', redirect_uri:redirect_uri

account.email #=> (retrieves the account’s e-mail address)
```

Even you can try out the API calls you would like to make at the OAuth 2.0 Playground by specifying the above scopes in the Step 1:

https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/